# Wordpress Gallery Issue - Edited Photos still showing old src

Tags: php, image, wordpress

When looping through the wordpress gallery to display images in a portfolio i can't seem to have wordpress return the edited images src. When i say edited i mean i've cropped and scaled the image using the wordpress image editor. For some strange reason all the src urls like right in the admin but when it comes to actually outputting the images through the loop i kept getting returned the original file. I know i could scale in photoshop etc but the face that i can't work it out is driving me nuts!

I've tried adding the edited image to another gallery but it still returns the src of the old unedited image. Is it even possible to have wp return edited image urls in a gallery loop?

```
$menu_sets_query = '';

$portfolio_items = -1;

$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'numberposts' => $portfolio_items, 
'post_status' => null, 
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
); 
$all_photo_arr = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Can we get a live example of what's happening?

Comment: you should give us more details and a live demo if it's posible

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're not using any WordPress page caching systems.
If you are, make sure your cache is cleared.

Comment: As well as any local caches or proxies.